# Override application root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have an application in iis available as `http://localhost/app/` which means that all relative links created by `UrlHelper` are resolved as `http://localhost/app/???`.

Example:
`Url.Content("~/images/background.png")` resolves into `/app/images/background.png`

Now the problem is that ISA server adds prefix to the application, so that application is available from outside as `http://foo.com/prefix/app/???`

Now mvc will handle the request correctly, because it still thinks that the request path is just `/app/???`, but it won't generate links with that prefix when using `UrlHelper`.

So the question is - is there any way to tell MVC to generate links with different virtual path than is defined in iis?

Example:
`Url.Content("~/images/background.png")` should resolve into `/prefix/app/images/background.png`

I really don't want to create own `UrlHelper` extensions because that won't affect stuff like `Html.ActionLink` or `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I have the exact same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately no. I eventually "solved" it by writing wrapper over url helper that just prefixed all them urls. You might be able to do some magic with changing the request url at `BeginRequest` or something as @Roman mentions, but I'm not sure whether it's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to get to the Request Context and modify the URL early in the request pipeline so that by the time UrlHelper fires, Request.RawUrl returns proper path with the prefix.  Great question as I will try to come up with a logic sometime soon.